# Execute SQL Plus SQL command from batch-cmd window hangs

Tags: windows, oracle, batch-file, sqlplus

I am trying to execute a PL-SQL statemtn in a file and log the results to a log file. It works, but the DOS window hangs and I have to manually close it.

Am I ending the SqlPlus session incorrectly?

```
rem SET TERMOUT OFF; 
SET SqlPlusExe=C:\Oracle\product\11203_32bit\CLIENT_1\bin\sqlplus.exe
SET MyUser=MyID
SET MyPassword=MyPwd
SET Host=RXODSDEV.CIGNA.COM
SET SqlFile=C:\Users\MyLanId\Desktop\SQLPlus\test.sql
SET LogFile=C:\Users\MyLanId\Desktop\SQLPlus\test.log

%SqlPlusExe% %MyUser%/%MyPassword%@%Host% @%SqlFile% >> %LogFile% 
quit;
/
```

Comment: Hmm. It looks like if I add the "quit" to the last line of the sql file it works.

Comment: You can't put input for a program into a batch file like that.  You could try `echo quit; | %SqlPlusExe%`...

Answer (score 0):

For Windows-scripting I recommend you to set the environment variable "LOCAL" ("TWO_TASK" on linux). The variable will specify you connection string.

```
set LOCAL=RXODSDEV.CIGNA.COM

REM Create the file to run
@(
   echo connect %MyUser%/%MyPassword% 
   echo @%SqlFile% 
   echo exit^;
) > %TEMP%\run.sql
sqlplus /nolog @%TEMP%\run.sql >> out.log
```

But who is doing DOS scripting these days? Powershell is so much more fun!

Comment: Nobody is doing "DOS" scripting these days. There is no DOS any more.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you find my launcher script useful, take a look at http://www.unix.com/windows-and-dos-issues-and-discussions/256021-windowss-batch-launcher-oracle-sql-linux-sh-scripts-available-here.html